# email alias to external email account

Tags: email

I wonder if this is possible:

Say, we have a self-employed sales staff, who uses gmail. I can set up an email account for him in our email system, and direct emails to his @gmail.com account. How can we set things up so that when he sends email out, the sender shows as @ instead of gmail? If this is not possible, then I will have to let him to use the email account created in our system directly..

many thx for any input...

Answer (score 3):

Gmail supports the use of aliases.  Check Setting, Accounts, Send Mail As

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this is possible, with a Gmail Alias, it's a monstrously bad idea, as you're effectively allowing information (some of which might be Company Proprietary) to leave your control.

Once it's out, it's not coming back.

Comment: Agree.  What is so horrible about making the sales guy use an email account directly on your mail system like the rest of the employees?  Who cares that he's "self-employed".  You should control mail flow for emails @ your domain and have full visibility into them.  Don't give into a whiny employee that says "I just want to use my Gmail."

Answer (score 0):

If he is sending email from gmail, then it's up to him to set things up so that it appears to come from the other domain. You can't do that on your system.